# Nesting MySQL queries to UPDATE or INSERT with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Using MySQL and PHP I'm making an index of the "amounts" table and grouping it by product, type, month, day, and hour. Then either updating a matching record in the "amounts_merged" table or inserting a new record if it does not already exist.

Here is the solution I came up with. But I'm not sure this is the best way to go about this. Any suggestions would be great.

```
$sql = "SELECT product, type, month, day, hour, AVG(amount) AS average_amount FROM amounts GROUP BY product, type, month, day, hour";
$result1 = @mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

    $average_amount = $row[average_amount];
    $product = $row[product];
    $type = $row[type];
    $month = $row[month];
    $day = $row[day];
    $hour = $row[hour];

    $sql = "UPDATE amounts_merged SET average_amount = '$average_amount' WHERE product = '$product' AND type = '$type' AND month = '$month' AND day = '$day' AND hour = '$hour'";
        $result2 = @mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error());

        $updated_rows = mysql_affected_rows();

        if ($updated_rows == 0) {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO amounts_merged (product, type, month, day, hour, average_amount)
                        VALUES ('$product', '$type', '$month', '$day', '$hour', '$average_amount')";
            $result3 = @mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error());


    }

}
```

Comment: Still amazes me, how this "method" to call SQL in PHP still survives after years and years with much more better solutions.

Comment: @Henrik P. Hessel what are the better solutions that you are referring to?

Comment: PDO or take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library

Comment: if you need a quick hack to try something out then it is the perfect way to go. PDO is an overhead if you just play around.

Comment: No, I disagree, mixing php and sql has great potential for potential bugs.

Comment: `ORM` is very often overkill, having a good database abstraction so you can easily filter, switch and trace queries & code is very handy, and `PDO` can fulfill that need, but is not the only solution out there. That being said, `mysql` is ancient, slow & not advisable. At the very _least_ use mysqli, but PDO _is_ probably the future for PHP apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a unique key and let MySQL handle it:

```
ALTER TABLE amounts_merged  ADD UNIQUE (product,type,month,day,hour)
```

In PHP:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO amounts_merged 
    (product,type,month,day,hour,average_amount)
    SELECT product, type, month, day, hour, AVG(amount) AS average_amount
    FROM amounts
    GROUP BY product, type, month, day, hour
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE average_amount = VALUES(average_amount);"
 mysql_query($sql, $con);
```

Some loose remarks:

- Don't quote variables that are integers or floats (don't know if they are, but I have my suspicions...
- Prepared statements are even more handy for both running more update queries then 1, and in preventing SQL injection.
- Having seperate columns for month/date/hour in your original `amounts` table is probably making live harder then need be, as with just having a timestamp/datetime you can *get* the data easily from those fiels, *and* you can still use all date functions easily on the original field.